# How can I apply the changes in runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimFlyertransportationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject JetFlame;
    public bool turnOffOn = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if (turnOffOn)
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void TurnAllAnimtorsOff(Transform root, bool onOff)
    {
        Animator[] animators = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>();

        foreach (Animator a in animators)
        {
            if (onOff)
            {
                a.enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                a.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need that if in runtime I change the turnOffOn flag state apply the changes in real time in the Update for all Animators and also for the JetFlame. Now it's only aply the changes in the editor before running the game.

Comment: Maybe you need apply the change in `Update`?

Comment: I would create a Public Setter for the `turnOffOn` to be able to trigger it from other Class, and then in the Update method called the `TurnAllAnimtorsOff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can anyway only do this in the UnityEditor you could use [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)

> This function is called when the script is loaded or a value is changed in the Inspector (Called in the editor only).

```
private void OnValidate()
{
    TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

    if(JetFlame) JetFlame.SetActive(!turnOffOn);
}
```

You also should use

```
Animator[] animators = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>(true);
```

by passing in `true` as parameter you also include inactive and disabled components!